# multiple countdown on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are the html code for countdown. I am using jquery.countdown.min.js plugin.

```
<ul id="example">
<li><span class="days">00</span><p class="days_text">Days</p></li>
        <li class="seperator">:</li>
        <li><span class="hours">00</span><p class="hours_text">Hours</p></li>
        <li class="seperator">:</li>
    <li><span class="minutes">00</span><p class="minutes_text">Minutes</p></li>
        <li class="seperator">:</li>
    <li><span class="seconds">00</span><p class="seconds_text">Seconds</p></li>
    </ul>

    <div id= "count" data-text="01/01/2016 05:06:59"></div>
```

and here are the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val1 = $('#count').data('text');

        $('#example').countdown({
            date: val1,
            offset: 0,
            day: 'Day',
            days: 'Days'
        }, function () {
            alert('Done!');
        });
    </script>
```

It is working fine and giving me the desired output. The limitation is i can use only one countdown timer per page. If i want to use multiple on same page then  i have to add multiple javascript code.

Below is the scenario.

```
<ul id="example">
        <div data-countdown="01/01/2016 05:06:59"></div>
         <div data-countdown="01/01/2017"></div>
         <div data-countdown="01/01/2018"></div>
        <div data-countdown="01/01/2020"></div>   
      </ul>
```

I tried below code but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this),finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
        $this.countdown({
            date: finalDate,
            offset: 0,
            day: 'Day',
            days: 'Days'
        }, function () {
            alert('Done!');

        });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3h9tyrvh/)

```
    <div id="example1" data-countdown="01/01/2016 05:06:59"></div>
    <div id="example2" data-countdown="01/01/2017"></div>
    <div id="example3" data-countdown="01/01/2018"></div>
    <div id="example4" data-countdown="01/01/2020"></div>   

$(function(){
   $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
      $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
         $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'))}).on('finish.countdown', function() {
            alert("Finish"); 
          });
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not an expert of javascript. Can you please show it in a fiddle. I appreciate if you can show working example.

Comment: Very nice. If i want to add alert box in this. Does it work?  alert('Time is finished.!');

Comment: here example1 works only when the YEAR difference is one year , for instance (01/07/2017 05:06:59) wont work

Comment: Am I the only one who ever got the error "TypeError: $this.countdown is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Javascript and html are friends. When you found something strange happened in the js code, validate the html first. In your case, if you stick on the "ul", use "ul—li—div" structure; otherwise use "div—div" or "nav—div" or "section—div" if applicable